# Attribute value is not displaying when called inside static block

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I am trying to show an attribute(Text area) in product page. My phtml file to call the attribute is `description.phtml` :

```
    <?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And I create a static block with this code:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
  <p> {{block type="core/template" template="page/description.phtml"}<p>  
</div>
```

Then I called my static block in `view.phtml` like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_details_tab')->toHtml() ?>
```

where the identifier of the static block is `product_details_tab`.

Instead of displaying the value given in the attribute field, It is displaying error  like:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDescription() on null`.

Help me to resolve this. Where have I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace from  `$this->getProduct()` to `Mage::registry('current_product')`

For exp :

```
 <?php $_description = Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute(Mage::registry('current_product'), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the block type, So replace

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
  <p> {{block type="core/template" template="page/description.phtml"}<p>  
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
  <p> {{block type="catalog/product" template="page/description.phtml"}<p>  
</div>
```

Now your page will find the product blog to get the product.

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I have upvoted your answer.